# How to prove to recipient that we are using public parameters correctly in lattice IBE

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, lattice-crypto, identity-based-encryption

Many lattice IBE scheme follow the scheme outlined in [ABB10](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-13190-5_28).

In ABB10, the ciphertext is

$c_0 = u^\top s + x$, where $u$ is a public parameter. (No consider message here.)

I want to ask:

Is it possible to make sure the ciphertext is generated following the scheme?

That is, can the sender provide a zero-knowledge proof that $c_1$ is generated from $us+x$, instead of $u's+x$?